# Commands after berks not running in batch file

Tags: batch-file, chef-infra, berkshelf

I have a batch file that runs a few processes to test and build my chef cookbooks

```
del test.tar.gz
berks vendor --delete
berks package test.tar.gz <- doesnt execute
```

--or--

```
del test.tar.gz
berks package test.tar.gz 
berks vendor --delete  <- doesnt execute
```

the problem is that no commands after the first berks command ever get executed.

I've tried adding several different commands after `berks vendor` however nothing will run, even though the previous command completes successfully.

I cant find anything in the documentation about this, how can I get all my commands to run?

Comment: Admittedly I know absolutely nothing about berks, but how are you expecting test.tar.gz to be passed to `berks package` after you've deleted the file?

Comment: Going to assume that BERKS is a batch file. If so, you need to use the CALL command.

Comment: @SomethingDark - the command `berks package test.tar.gz` creates the file, rather than consumes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binstub we create on Windows is `berks.bat`. So you need to use `call berks.bat` instead. This is a weird limitation of Windows batch scripts.

Comment: This is one of those answers that makes you feel dumb once you know whats going on.